# How to add correct Last update in Postings (the_modified_time)

Tags: front-end, date-time, publish, posting

Having little issue with following:

We want to add "Last update" after making important corrections or additional text/images to existing Postings.
Using following code (hardcoded) does in a way almost what I want:

```
<span style="font-size:85%">Last update <u><time datetime="<?php the_modified_time('d-m-y'); ?>"> <?php the_modified_time('l  j  F, Y'); ?></time></u></span>
```

But doing in that way it results in showing -always- the so named "Last update", even when it is just published and not been updated at all.
We would love to make it so that it only will be shown when really some updates are done, and the optimum would be as a plugin.
So I must be doing some wrong, is it possible at all and if so, how to do this?

*Note:
 it is meant for the front-end in Postings and not as a widget in the sidebar, neither for the back-end.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could compare `post_date` to `post_modified` and only echo your content if they do not match.

```
// inside a Loop
if ($post->post_date != $post->post_modified) { ?>
  <span style="font-size:85%">Last update <u><time datetime="<?php the_modified_time('d-m-y'); ?>"> <?php the_modified_time('l  j  F, Y'); ?></time></u></span><?php
}
```

If you want "significant" updates, though, you will need to determine what counts as significant and save your own data. WordPress is going to update that "last modified" value with *any* update, however trivial. Something like this:

```
function save_non_trivial_edit_date_wpse_103622($pid) {
  if (
    (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) 
    || (defined('DOING_AJAX') && DOING_AJAX) 
    || isset($_REQUEST['bulk_edit'])
  ) {
    return;
  } else {
    update_post_meta($pid,'_sig_update_date',time());
  }
}
add_action('save_post', 'save_non_trivial_edit_date_wpse_103622');
```

Which you'd retrieve with:

```
// in the Loop
$sig_update = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_sig_update_date',true); ?>
<span style="font-size:85%">Last update <u><time datetime="<?php echo date('d-m-y',$sig_update); ?>"> <?php echo date('d-m-y',$sig_update); ?></time></u></span><?php
```

Even that is a fairly trivial "significant update" tracker. You can change the update just by saving, even if nothing is changed. You'd have to start comparing revision word counts (or something) to do better. You will have to think that through and work out what counts as "significant".

Comment: Thank you for the extra input, we will have to brainstorm about the *comparing revision word counts*.
If, then we will try to find a way, else "I'll be back" :).

Answer (score 0):

You could add a comparison between the last modified time and the original created time, and only show the last modified time if they are different. Something like this:

```
<?php if ( $post->post_date != $post->post_modified ) : ?>
<span style="font-size:85%">
  Last update 
  <u>
    <time datetime="<?php the_modified_time('d-m-y'); ?>">
      <?php the_modified_time('l  j  F, Y'); ?>
    </time>
  </u>
</span>
<?php endif; ?>
```